# Trying to prevent a second click before response of the first

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, user-interface, webforms

I'd like to prevent a button click to happen a second time while the response of the fist click has not yet returned (to prevent the user to "double click" too fast or if the page is taking some time to work doesn't trigger a second click).

Originally, my page was something like this (already putting the html output, kind of):

```
<html>
    <head><title>test</title></head>
    <body>
        <form name="form" method="post" action="dostuff" id="form" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="submit" name="cnt$ctl00$uiins" value="Do It" onclick="return confirm('Really do it?');" id="cnt_ctl00_uiins" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

It was working as intended, the confirm was called and if "OK" would post, if not just nothing would happen; great. Then i tryed to implement this javascript on the "onclick" of the button, and i find out it disables the button (as intended), but it also prevents the submit from happening.

The script:

```
<script>
    function safeConfirm(cn,ms)
    {
        $(cn).prop('disabled',true);
        if(confirm(ms)) { return true; }
        else
        {
            $(cn).prop('disabled',false);
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

And the "onclick" of the button (that was filled in the button control "OnClientClick" property) changed from 'onclick="return confirm('Really do it?');"' to:

`onclick="return safeConfirm(this,'Really do it?');"`

What's wrong here? Am i missing something, seems to me should work.

Comment: Assuming that's the built-in `confirm` (halts js execution) then instead of `return true` do `$("form")[0].submit()` - note specifically the `[0]`

Comment: Here's a better and working way to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/caj7nyeg/

Comment: Chris, strange thing - your code (on jsfiddle, not my application) runs on Chrome, but i'm testing all browsers, doesn't work on OperaGX for some reason

Comment: "this" refers to the form.  So you're disabling the whole form.

Comment: not really pcalkins, the "this" in the safeConfirm argument on the function, and doing a step by step on Chrome it brings the button id

Comment: also, Chris - your answer works so i guess this question is over, since my problem not seems to be browser compatibility - can you put an answer here for me to mark as answered?